# How to add a custom row class or ID to type table render elements

Tags: 8, theming

I'm trying to add row ID's for a custom table I implemented via a custom module. But when I append an ID to the `'#attributes'` array it becomes the table ID, not the row ID. How can I define IDs for rows?

This is what I have so far:

```
$form['table'] = [
  '#type' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header_table,
  '#rows' => $rows,
  '#attributes'=> ['id' => 'IdforRow'],
  '#empty' => t('No Data found'),
  '#prefix' => '<b>Total Tenders : '.@$count.'</b><br>',
  '#suffix' => '',
];
```

Comment: If you want add ID for row, you have to add attributes at $rows not at table.

Comment: Can you try this code? `$row = array('data' => 'some data'); $rows[] = array('data' => $row, 'class' => 'some class'); );` Or maybe the following one. `$row = array('data' => 'some data'); $rows[] = array('data' => $row, 'class' => array('some class'));` See also https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2016-04-21/add-class-in-row-with-theme-table.

Comment: no its not working

Comment: even i try this too `foreach ($vars['rows'] as $key => $row)
{
  $vars['rows'][$key] = array('data' => $row, 'class' => array('myclass'));
}`

Answer (score 0):

The row should be prepared as given below, to have id and class for each rows.

```
$rows[] = [
  'id' => $row_id,
  'class' => 'row-class',
  'data' => [
    $cell1_data,
    $cell2_data,
  ]
]
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to add the ID in an array format like below:

```
$form['table'] = [
    '#type' => 'table',
    '#header' =>  $header_table,
    '#rows' => $rows,
    '#attributes'=>[
      'id' => 'IdforRow'
    ],
    '#empty' => t('No Data found'),
    '#prefix' => '<b>Total Tenders : '.@$count.'</b><br>',
    '#suffix' => '',
];
```

Comment: ID never comes as array. OP has no problem with their table ID. OP wants row IDs.

Comment: its showing same as my question